# How do I apply skeletal animation from a .x (Direct X) file?

Tags: opengl, animation, blender, skeletal-animation

Using the .x format to export a model from Blender, I can load a mesh, armature and animation. I have no problems generating the mesh and viewing models in game. Additionally, I have animations and the armature properly loaded into appropriate data structures.

My problem is properly applying the animation to the models. I have the framework for applying the models and the code for selecting animations and stepping through frames.

From what I understand, the `AnimationKey`s inside the `AnimationSet` supplies the transformations to transform the bind pose to the pose in the animated frame. As small example:

```
Animation {
  {Armature_001_Bone}
  AnimationKey { 
    2; //Position
    121; //number of frames
    0;3;     0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000;;,
    1;3;     0.000000, 0.000000, 0.005524;;,
    2;3;     0.000000, 0.000000, 0.022217;;,
    ...
  }
  AnimationKey { 
    0; //Quaternion Rotation 
    121;
    0;4;   -0.707107, 0.707107, 0.000000, 0.000000;;,
    1;4;   -0.697332, 0.697332, 0.015710, 0.015710;;,
    2;4;   -0.684805, 0.684805, 0.035442, 0.035442;;,
    ...
  }
  AnimationKey { 
    1; //Scale
    121;
    0;3;     1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000;;,
    1;3;     1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000;;,
    2;3;     1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000;;,
    ...
  }
}
```

So, to apply frame 2, I would take the position, rotation and scale from frame 2, create a transformation matrix (call it `Transform_A`) from them and apply that matrix the vertices controlled by `Armature_001_Bone` at their weights. So I'd stuff `TransformA` into my shader and transform the vertex. Something like:

```
vertexPos = vertexPos * bones[ int(bfs_BoneIndices.x) ] * bfs_BoneWeights.x;
```

Where `bfs_BoneIndices` and `bfs_BoneWeights` are values specific to the current vertex.

When loading in the mesh vertices, I transform them by the `rootTransform` and the `meshTransform`. This ensures they're oriented and scaled correctly for viewing the bind pose.

The problem is when I create that transformation matrix (using the position, rotation and scale from the animation), it doesn't properly transform the vertex. There's likely more to it than just using the animation data. I also tried applying the bone transform hierarchies, still no dice. Basically I end up with some twisted models. It should also be noted that I'm working in openGL, so any matrix transposes that might need to be applied should be considered.

**What data do I need and how do I combine it for applying .x animations to models?**

I've made some mock ups of what this looks like, in case that's useful.

First I wanted to just test the translation, this is a bobbing head, what it looks like in Blender:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAc4B.gif

And what it looks like in game (don't mind the colors):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj2du.gif

Then for just rotation, the animation was the head rotating 360 degrees around the vertical axis. This is what that looks like in game:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVyUW.gif

Note, there should be no tilt, only rotation like a merry-go-round.

**Update**

I have the translation part of the animation working. But it feels kind of hacky and I don't see how to apply it to the rotation.

The translation works by taking these steps:

1. Take the position from the animation frame and swap the `y` and `z` values
2. Translate the transformation matrix by the altered position
3. Transpose the transformation matrix
4. Apply the transformation matrix to the vertices

So that's how it *can* work, but how is it supposed to work generally for position, scale and rotation?

Comment: Did you transform the vertex with the inverse bind pose matrix before applying the skinning?

Comment: I have, it has an effect, but it's not a desired one. It appears affect the visual representation of the model (inverting all the normals, looks like), but has no effect on the movement/rotation/scale.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot illustrating the problem?

Comment: @r2d2rigo I've updated with animated gifs.

Comment: If the translation shows up as skewing/rotating (like in your gif) then it sounds like the matrix formats are mismatching. Try transposing the matrices as you load them?

Comment: @DanielCarlsson That's getting there. As you can see in my update, the translations work when swapping y and z, and *transposing*. But how would I do the same for the rotation? What's the equivalent of swapping the y and z and transposing a quaternion?

Comment: I'm mostly brainstorming here, but if the vector order (xyz,zxy) differs between .x and opengl you would get some fun effects. The fact that transposing helps means that it uses column (or row) vector for the position, instead of the other way around. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations has a description of rotations for 2D. I don't quite know how to modify a quaternion though. Or the difference between .x and openGL formats

Comment: @Byte56  Ah, so you do have to change handedness. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Discussion about changing the handedness of quaternions http://www.gamedev.net/topic/555078-convert-quaternions-from-d3d-to-opengl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I put some more time toward this and got it working for multiple bones, and considerably less hack-like (though still a little). The system I had in place originally was almost correct. However, the main problems were:

1. Blender saves Quaternions in **W, X, Y, Z** format. I was loading them *X, Y, Z, W*.
2. My code for converting a Quaternion to a matrix was incorrect. I'm actually still not sure why this is incorrect, but I know the following code works, as part of my Quaternion class:

   ```
   public Matrix4f toMatrix() {
       Matrix4f tmpMatrix = new Matrix4f();
       if (this.length() > 0)
           this.normalise();

       float xx = this.x * this.x;
       float xy = this.x * this.y;
       float xz = this.x * this.z;
       float wx = this.x * this.w;

       float yy = this.y * this.y;
       float yz = this.y * this.z;
       float wy = this.y * this.w;

       float zz = this.z * this.z;
       float wz = this.z * this.w;
       //note the "* -1"s
       //I needed those to make the same matrices Blender was expecting
       tmpMatrix.m00 = (1.0f - 2.0f * (yy + zz)) * -1;
       tmpMatrix.m01 = (       2.0f * (xy - wz)) * -1;
       tmpMatrix.m02 =        2.0f * (xz + wy);
       tmpMatrix.m03 = 0;

       tmpMatrix.m10 =        2.0f * (xy + wz);
       tmpMatrix.m11 = 1.0f - 2.0f * (xx + zz);
       tmpMatrix.m12 = (       2.0f * (yz - wx)) * -1;
       tmpMatrix.m13 = 0;

       tmpMatrix.m20 =        2.0f * (xz - wy);
       tmpMatrix.m21 =        2.0f * (yz + wx);
       tmpMatrix.m22 = (1.0f - 2.0f * (xx + yy)) * -1;
       tmpMatrix.m23 = 0;
       return tmpMatrix;
   }
   ```

Other than that, it's just:

`finalMatrix = boneMatrix * skinMatrix * invertedBindMatrix;`

Note that the `boneMatrix` should be using the animated matrices for each bone instead of the bind matrices. It should also get all it's parent matrices like so:

```
private Matrix4f getBoneMatrix() {
        if (parent == null) {
            return Matrix4f.mul(Matrix4f.mul(parentArmature.getBindMatrix(), parentArmature.getArmatureRootMatrix(), null), boneMatrix, null);
        } else {
            return Matrix4f.mul(parent.getBoneMatrix(), boneMatrix, null);
        }
    }
```

And it works. Leave a comment if you need clarification.

Comment: I wrote some more general info about getting this working at my blog: http://www.byte56.com/2012/12/the-blender-connection.html

Answer (score 3):

> It should also be noted that I'm working in openGL, so any matrix transposes that might need to be applied should be considered.

Maybe that's the key, have you tried negating some Z-coordinates around to convert from DirectX left-handed coordinates to OpenGL right-handed ones?

You could negate all Zs before applying your transformations, and re-negate when done, see if the output gets any better.

**EDIT**

Swapping the Y and Z-coordinates is another way to change handedness. So you do have to adapt your transformations, [check this paper for details](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LeftHandedToRightHanded.pdf).

The fact that you have to transpose you matrix also means you going from row-major to column-major or the other way around. This should be less complicated to handle, you'll probably just have to find the right "place" to do it in your pipeline. I'm just guessing, but doing it on quaternions could simply means changing them to matrices, transpose, and go back quaternions, if your Math lib offers your this option.

Comment: Kind of telling me what I already know here...

Comment: Well, you didn't mention handedness in your question, and I believe it's at least a part of your problem. I can't assume you do or don't know that DirectX and OpenGL are following different conventions on this point (this is actually a [bit more complex](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/62427/51067)). Note that this might help *other* people reading this question to see it mentioned, which is kind of the point of this whole website.

Comment: Fair enough, you're right. I only hinted at the fact I knew about the conversions that needed to take place when I mentioned using OpenGL and the transposes that needed to happen.